# Pyinstaller creating non-working files

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I have installed python 2.7.14 on Windows XP and it is running very well.

I then used following command to install pyinstaller:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

It installed pyinstaller version 3.3

I then tried it with a simple file that contained only:

```
print("Hello World.")
```

I used following command:

```
pyinstaller -F hello.py
```

It created a build and a dist folder and in the dist folder a file named hello.exe is created. However, on trying to run it, I get following error message in a dialog box:

```
C:\myfolder\hello.exe is not a valid win32 application
```

On closing the dialog box, following appears on the terminal:

```
Access is denied.
```

Why is pyinstaller creating non-working executables? Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

because some update broke Windows XP compatibility。

via:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2876
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/2974

you can still use version 3.2.1.

`pip install PyInstaller==3.2.1`